Sunmi V2 pro Print
I have an app I developed, but I don't know how to print it on Sunmi V2 pro without using RAMBT. I want it to print directly from my app installed in Sunmi V2 pro.
I tried looking at the sdk but it's only available for bluetooth or wifi. My App is in Sunmi v2 pro and cannot be printed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
